# compare strings in ifdef directive

Tags: c, macros, conditional-compilation

I pass a macto during compilation:

`% gcc -DIDENT="abcd" app.c`

What is the right way to check during compilation the macro? For example the following works, but throws warning:

```
#ifdef IDENT == "abcd"
printf("abcd\n");
#endif
```

warning: extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive.

Comment: `#ifdef IDENT = "abcd"` is nonsense. `#if IDENT == "abcd"` could theoretically work, but probably will be forbidden.

Comment: There was a typo in my post, should be ==  What is the reason of warning?

Comment: Yup, can only use integer expressions in preprocessor conditionals.

Comment: @Mark `#ifdef IDENT` is shorthand for `#if defined(IDENT)` (defined is a preprocessor-keyword) and that's how the preprocessor parses it. `== "abcd"` is the extra tokens it's not expecting there.

Comment: There is no "right way to check during compilation" - it cannot be done. The only things you can do are: a) check if a macro by a given name has been defined, b) do calculations on *integer* values, and act if the result is zero or nonzero.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, just to clarify, I think you mean that those are the only *conditional compilation* alternatives available via the C preprocessor.  For the benefit of those with little C experience, I observe that you can do other kinds of things with the preprocessor, too, especially source inclusion and macro processing.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's [not exactly true](https://godbolt.org/g/UySZKw); example shows evaluation on _tokens_ using pattern matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#ifdef tests whether a symbol is defined, not what the value is, so is valid only as

```
#ifdef SYMBOL
```

#if expression will test whether an expression is true, however is limited to integers only.

For more information, see the gcc preprocessor manual:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html#Ifdef

Answer (score 4):

`#ifdef` in typical use is just about _whether the symbol is defined or not.  It's not about its value, it's whether it's defined/exists.

```
#define IDENT
#ifdef IDENT {yields true}
```

Vs.

```
//#define IDENT {not defined}
#ifdef IDENT {yields false because line above is commented out
```